# Java - simple graphics and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, graphics

Well since you folks helped me a lot with my last project, I thought I might find some assistance with the current one :)

The project has us practicing recursion and objects (just started learning about the latter). So we first create a "BasicStar", later a "Snowflake", then comes the "SuperSnowflake" and finally the dreaded "KochCurve".

So I the "BasicStar" was quite easy, and now the idea of the "Snowflake" is to recursively draw "BasicStar"s with smaller radiuses. I have uploaded three images (basic star, which I did successfully, snowflake the way it should be, and my snowflake) so it's easy to understand what I mean. My recursive method draws something very different, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

(P.S. The `Main` and `Painter` classes were made by the university faculty so even if there are things to improve there it won't be relevant. The rest was written by myself)

`Main`:

```
package recursion;

import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * the class main get from the user the shape he wish to draw,
 * and call the drew method of the desired shape .
 */
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {        


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter the number of the shape you wish to draw:\n" +
            " 1-example\n" +
            " 2-BasicStar\n" +
            " 3-Snowflake\n" +
            " 4-SuperSnowflake\n" +
            " 5-KochCurve\n" +
            " 6-KochSnowflake\n");
    int shape = sc.nextInt();

    // chooses which shape to draw based on the number received
    switch(shape){
    /*
     *  An example given to you so you can see how the painted works.
     *  This example opens a frame, and draws a red line.
     */
    case 1:
        drawExample();
        break;
    case 2:
        drawBasicStar();
        break;
    case 3:
        drawSnowflake();
        break;
    case 4:
        drawSuperSnowflake();
        break;
    case 5:
        drawKochCurve();
        break;
    case 6:
        drawKochSnowflake();
        break;
    default: System.out.println("invalid shape");
    }

    sc.close();
}

// Draw the example line
public static void drawExample(){
    Painter.draw("example");
}

// Draw a BasicStar
public static void drawBasicStar(){
    Painter.draw("BasicStar");
}

// Draw a Snowflake
public static void drawSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("Snowflake");
}

// Draw a SuperSnowflake
public static void drawSuperSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("SuperSnowflake");
}

// Draw a KochCurve
public static void drawKochCurve(){
    Painter.draw("KochCurve");
}

// Draw a KochSnowflake
public static void drawKochSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("KochSnowflake");
}

}
```

`Painter`:

```
package recursion;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/*
 * open a frame named aShape and drew the given shape 
 */

public class Painter extends Component {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static int SIZE = 600;
private static Painter painter;
private static Graphics g;
private static String shape = null;

// Create a frame and display it
public static void draw(String aShape) {
    shape = aShape;        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(shape);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    painter =  new Painter();
    frame.add(painter, null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// returns the Frame's width
public static int getFrameWidth () {
    return painter.getSize().width;
}

// returns the Frame's height
public static int getFrameHeight () {
    return painter.getSize().height;
}

// changes the color of the lines to be drawn
public static void setColor (String color) {
    if (color.equals("red")){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }           
    else if (color.equals("blue")){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);  
    }
    else if (color.equals("green")){
        g.setColor(Color.green);  
    }       
}

public static void drawLine (Pixel p1, Pixel p2) {
    drawLine((int)Math.round(p1.getX()),(int)Math.round(p1.getY()),(int)Math.round(p2.getX()),(int)Math.round(p2.getY()));
}

// Draw a line on the frame
public static void drawLine (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    g.drawLine(x1, getFrameHeight()-y1, x2, getFrameHeight()-y2);

}

// Set the default size of the window frame to SIZE*SIZE pixels
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
}

// paint the frame - draw the shape given (call the draw method in that shape object)
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Painter.g = g;
    try{
        Object myShape = (Class.forName("recursion." + shape)).newInstance();
        Object [] objs = null;
        Class [] classes = null;
        (Class.forName("recursion." + shape)).getMethod("draw", classes).invoke(myShape, objs);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Can't handle shape " + shape);
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(e.getCause());

    }



 }

}
```

`Pixel`:

```
package recursion;

public class Pixel {
private double x;
private double y;

public Pixel(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

public Pixel(double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Pixel(Pixel center){
    this();
    if(center != null){
        this.x = center.x;
        this.y = center.y;
    }
}

public double getX(){
    return x;
}
public double getY(){
    return y;
}
public void translate(Pixel p){
    this.x = this.x + p.x;
    this.y = this.y + p.y;
}
public void rotateRelativeToAxesOrigin(double theta){
    double tempX = this.x;
    double tempY = this.y;
    this.x = ((tempX)*(Math.cos(theta)) - ((tempY)*(Math.sin(theta))));
    this.y = ((tempX)*(Math.sin(theta)) - ((tempY)*(Math.cos(theta))));
}
public void rotateRelativeToPixel(Pixel p1, double theta){
    double tempX = this.x;
    double tempY = this.y;
    Pixel translatedPixel = new Pixel(tempX-p1.getX(), tempY-p1.getY());
    translatedPixel.rotateRelativeToAxesOrigin(theta);
    this.x = translatedPixel.getX() + p1.getX();
    this.y = translatedPixel.getY() + p1.getY();
}
}
```

`BasicStar`:

```
package recursion;

public class BasicStar {
private Pixel center;
private double radius;

public BasicStar(){
    double height = Painter.getFrameHeight()/2;
    double width = Painter.getFrameWidth()/2;
    this.center = new Pixel (width, height);
    double maxRadius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
    this.radius = maxRadius/4;
}

public BasicStar(Pixel center, double radius){
    this.center = new Pixel(center);
    this.radius = radius;
}

public Pixel getCenter(){
    return new Pixel(center);
}
public double getRadius(){
    return this.radius;
}
public void draw(){
    Pixel begin = new Pixel(this.center); 
    Pixel end = new Pixel(center.getX() + getRadius(), center.getY());

            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);
            end.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (2*Math.PI)/6);
            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);
            end = new Pixel(center.getX() + getRadius(), center.getY());
            end.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (4*Math.PI)/6);
            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);
            end = new Pixel(center.getX() + getRadius(), center.getY());
            end.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (6*Math.PI)/6);
            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);
            end = new Pixel(center.getX() + getRadius(), center.getY());
            end.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (8*Math.PI)/6);
            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);
            end = new Pixel(center.getX() + getRadius(), center.getY());
            end.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (10*Math.PI)/6);
            Painter.drawLine(begin, end);

}
}
```

`Snowflake`:

```
package recursion;

public class Snowflake {
private BasicStar basic;
private int depth;

public Snowflake(){
    double height = Painter.getFrameHeight()/2;
    double width = Painter.getFrameWidth()/2;
    Pixel center = new Pixel (width, height);
    double maxRadius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
    double radius = maxRadius/4;
    this.basic = new BasicStar(center, radius);
    this.depth = 2;
}

public Snowflake(BasicStar basic, int depth){
    this();
    if(basic!=null){
        this.basic = basic;
        this.depth = depth;
    }
}

public int getDepth(){
    return this.depth;
}

public BasicStar getBasic(){
    return this.basic;
}

public double getRadius(BasicStar basic){
    return this.basic.getRadius();
}

public Pixel getBasicCenter(BasicStar basic){
    return this.basic.getCenter();
}

public void draw(){
    draw(this.depth, basic.getCenter(), basic.getRadius());
}

private void draw(int depth, Pixel center, double radius){
    BasicStar basic = new BasicStar(center, radius);

    if(depth==1){
        basic.draw();
    }
    else{
        Pixel p = new Pixel(center.getX() + radius, center.getY());
        draw(depth - 1, p, (radius/3));
        for(int i=0; i<6; i=i+1){
            p.rotateRelativeToPixel(center, (2*Math.PI)/6);
            BasicStar temp = new BasicStar(p, radius/3);
            temp.draw();
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: BasicStar]

[image: Snowflake]

[image: My Snowflake]

Comment: It looks like it's time to do some testing and debugging. Use a debugger to help you first to identify your error since you've not yet done that and this is a critical step that must be achieved before you can solve it.

Comment: About that - I actually tried but I ran into a different problem - since I have nothing in my "main" method, I have no idea how to use "Step Into" and figure it out - I tried setting a breakpoint in my recursive method but all it does when I try "Debug file" is it stops on my breakpoint, then I hit "f5" (Step Into), and it just continues and draws everything.. it doesn't continue line-by-line as it should.

Comment: Just as a side note: That's a nice fractal you have there, but it's not the [Koch Snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake)

Comment: are you sure you want to use reflections to handle the case differentiation in the paint method?

Comment: @tobias_k that's just the regular snowflake. The Koch snowflake will come later in the project.

Comment: @Simiil The Painter and Main classes were written by the faculty and are not to be modified by us students :)

Comment: This looks overly complicated to me. Is the system design part of the assignment?

Comment: No - just writing the recursive methods to draw the different types of snowflakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks overly complicated to me. To be honest, I did not read all your code, but you can create a simple recursive function for drawing a snowflake just like this:

```
public void drawSnowflake(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size, int level) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 360; a += 60) {
        double rad = a * Math.PI / 180;
        int x2 = (int) (x + Math.cos(rad) * size);
        int y2 = (int) (y + Math.sin(rad) * size);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
        if (level > 0) {
            drawSnowflake(g, x2, y2, size/3, level-1);
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is: It draws the lines of a star using basic trigonometry (don't forget to convert angles to radians!), and then calls itself with a smaller `size` and `level` for the positions at the ends of the spikes. Embedding this into an actual GUI is left as an excercise to the reader.

[image: Example snoflake with size=100 and levels=3]

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! I now succeeded to fix my recursive method (from your method I understood what was going wrong with mine).